# Solving a hard algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is:

> Rectangular floor mats have an area of $x^2 + 2x - 15 \text{ cm}^2$.
>   The length is $x + 5\text{ cm}$, and the width is $100\text{ cm}$. How do I find out the value of $x$, and from there the length of the mat? The equation to find the width is $$\frac{x^2+2x-15}{\text{length}}$$

Comment: Can you factor $x^2+2x-15$?

Comment: Area of rectangle $=$ length $\times$ width. Use that and solve the quadratic equation.

Comment: There isn't a quadratic equation involved in this I believe John

Comment: @Kiwi You are right, see my hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. One may solve, for $x>0$,
$$
\frac{x^2+2x-15}{x+5}=100
$$ or
$$
\frac{(x+5)(x-3)}{x+5}=100
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah, so the (x+5)'s cancel out, meaning x-3=100, so x is 103, meaning length is 108. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Kiwi We have $x^2+2x-15=(x^2+2x+1)-16=(x+1)^2-4^2=[(x+1)-4][(x+1)+4]=(x-3)(x+5)$.

Answer (score -1):

The area of the rectangular mat is given by the product of its length and width:

Area = Length × Width

The area of the mat is x^2 + 2x - 15 cm^2, the width is 100 cm, and the length is x + 5 cm. Therefore, we can write:

x^2 + 2x - 15 = (x + 5) × 100

Expanding the right-hand side, we get:

x^2 + 2x - 15 = 100x + 500

Simplifying and collecting like terms, we get:

x^2 - 98x + 515 = 0

We can solve this quadratic equation using the quadratic formula:

x = [-b ± sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)] / 2a

where a = 1, b = -98, and c = 515. Plugging in these values, we get:

x = [98 ± sqrt(98^2 - 4(1)(515))] / 2(1)

Simplifying, we get:

x = [98 ± sqrt(9604 - 2060)] / 2

x = [98 ± sqrt(7544)] / 2

x = [98 ± 2sqrt(1886)] / 2

x = 49 ± sqrt(1886)

We reject the negative root since length and width cannot be negative. Therefore, the value of x is:

x = 49 + sqrt(1886)

To find the length of the mat, we can substitute this value of x into the expression for the length:

Length = x + 5

Length = 54 + sqrt(1886) cm